# Scala: Add to list not adding to list

Tags: mongodb, scala

I am trying to add an item to a mongo DBObject list like so:

```
var retVal:Seq[DBObject] = List()

statuses.foreach(status => {
  val statusBuilder = MongoDBObject.newBuilder
  statusBuilder += "status" -> status.status
  statusBuilder += "name" -> status.name
  statusBuilder += "percentage" -> status.percentage

  retVal ++ statusBuilder.result
  retVal.++(statusBuilder.result)
})
//retVal is empty here
```

The problem is that, though there are no errors, nothing is actually added to the list. I am confused as to why this is the case. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have to assign to a list 
`retVal = retVal ++ statusBuilder.result`

Answer (score 1):

`Why not use a .map?`

```
val retVal: Seq[DBObject] = statuses.map{
  status => 
    val statusBuilder = MongoDBObject.newBuilder
    statusBuilder += "status" -> status.status
    statusBuilder += "name" -> status.name
    statusBuilder += "percentage" -> status.percentage

    statusBuilder.result
})
```

Comment: I did actually end up going that route